# Access Control of hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am a beginner with hyperledger composer, I am not clear with ACL (access control) in hyperledger composer. Sorry, if my question have problem.

1. Why we need ACL?
2. When we use it?
3. Where we use it?

Comment: read this [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To control access to resources on the ledger, or the kinds of CRUD operations (can I create an asset, can I update an asset), or kind of transaction types a participant of the business network can perform.
2. Because you want to apply access control - security 101 !
3. It is applied usually within the realms of a business network. So if I have a business network called 'Commodity Trading' I may only wish 'Trader 1' (a participant) to see his own historical trades on the business network - and not see others' trades. Yet I may allow him (by access rules) to be able to execute certain trade types, because of his role, in that Trade Brokerage. You get the picture.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ACL stands for Access control language and constitutes an important part of our composer network. Hyperledger as we know is a permissioned blockchain and ACL helps in achieving that. It helps in writing rules which define the different access levels of any participant of the ecosystem. We can define whether a participant can CREATE, READ, UPDATE or DELETE asset. We can restrict their access to the assets as well.We use ACL whenever there is are participant at different levels in our network and we don't need each of them to perform every operation on the assets.

You must go through this link once : https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/reference/acl_language